yellow pieces refusing to capture red pieces in a JavaScript checkers game
I wrote a function to check if a red piece can move with an arithmetic error where I was telling the program to get the wrong cell, but that is why proof reading your function is always good before using it.
My checkers game plays quite fine and the yellow player starts and makes a move followed by the red piece, check out the code from this fiddle , the issue is that when a yellow player initiates a capture, the red piece jumps over as expected but the yellow piece does not capture in return.
Please help me get rid of this error, I used Fiddle because Stack Overflow seems to have issues with the maximum character length of the body and my JavaScript code is 732 lines long
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css"/>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="playerA"></div>
    <center><table id="checkertable"></table></center>
    <div id="playerA"></div>
</body>
</html>

body{
    background:green;
}
/*style the table*/
.table{
    margin:auto;
    width:560px;
    height:560px;
}
.square{
    width:70px;
    height:70px;
}
.white{
    background-color:mintcream;
}
.brown{
    background-color:chocolate;
}
/*styles for the pieces*/
.gold-piece {
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    background-color: gold;
    width: 80%;
    height: 80%;
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin: 10%;
}

.red-piece {
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    background-color:orangered;
    width: 80%;
    height: 80%;
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin: 10%;
}

/*style for styling a selected piece*/
.selected-piece{
   border:2px solid white;
}


Can you add assumptions about how this game should behave, like if a player jumps over other does it gets one more chance etc. As currently on initial try yellow seems to work fine.

@YashMaheshwari, the assumptions are that if the current player has more than one captures to make then the script should allow it until no more captures can be performed by the same player

@YashMaheshwari, its the English version of checkers and I have a problem with the script not allowing a player to make captures to the last possible empty square for the current player, can you help me with that?
